# Retrieve/create recordset from SQL Server data in Excel vba

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, sspi, sqloledb

I want to access / retrieve / create recordset from SQL Server in Excel vba.

I tried following methods but they return an error.

Code 1:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=192.168.0.204; Database=REPORTdb2"
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
conn.Open sConnString 
Set rs = conn.Execute("select * from Table1;")
```

at the line `conn.Open sConnString` an error occurs:

> Invalid authorization specification

Code2:

```
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=192.168.0.204;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=ReportDB2;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open sConnString 
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table1;")
```

It throws an error

> Cannot generate SSPI context

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the Server using SSMS in order to validate the IP and that your Windows account is allowed to connect to the server? BTW, I am sure you have set a reference in the VBE to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 or above`?

Comment: sorry I'm new to VBA but I can access using create connection from excel option Data-->from other source-->From Sql Server.  There I use ip address only. And it can access perfectly now I want to access data without set the connection file i.e. directly coding from Module. And  Ref. is correction i.e. 2.8

Comment: If the below solution solved your problem then please close this question like so: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Otherwise, please do let me know what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

The following code [requires in the VBE a reference](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx) to `Microsoft Active Data Objects 2.8 Library` or above:

```
Public Sub AdoTestConnection()
Dim conServer As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstResult As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strDatabase As String
Dim strServer As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set conServer = New ADODB.Connection
conServer.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; " _
    & "DATA SOURCE=192.168.0.204; " _
    & "INITIAL CATALOG=REPORTdb2; " _
    & "User ID=sa;" _
    & "Password="
On Error GoTo SQL_ConnectionError
conServer.Open
On Error GoTo 0

Set rstResult = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "set nocount on; "
strSQL = strSQL & "select * from Table1;"
rstResult.ActiveConnection = conServer
On Error GoTo SQL_StatementError
rstResult.Open strSQL
On Error GoTo 0

'To copy the result to a sheet you may use the following code
'It will copy your table 'Table1' to the first sheet in your Excel file.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rstResult

Exit Sub

SQL_ConnectionError:
MsgBox "Problems connecting to the server." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
Exit Sub

SQL_StatementError:
MsgBox "Connection established. Yet, there is a problem with the SQL syntax." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

With the included error handling for

1. establishing a connection to the SQL server and
2. trying to pass an T-SQL command to the server for processing

you should be able to easily troubleshoot the problem for connecting to the server.
The above code will only return a 1 upon success (for a test run). Afterwards, you can substitute your SQL command for the one in the above example.

Comment: Message Appear : Problems connecting to the server.
Aborting...
You can see in my Code2 it gives an error for  SSPI context

Comment: Did you set a reference to `Microsoft Active Data Objects 2.8 Library` in the VBE as mentioned in the solution? Also, try changing `INITIAL CATALOG=REPORTdb2;` in the above sample to `INITIAL CATALOG=master;`.

Comment: Yes, I already mark for 2.8 Library and for catalog name is correct its REPORTDB2

Comment: When you can connect to the server with `Data-->from other source-->From Sql Server` do you select `Use Windows Authentication` or do you use `Use the following User Name and Password`? SSPI means that it is using windows authentication (the first option). If you enter a user name and a password then the VBA code needs to be changed.

Comment: Oh! from the option I use user name as sa and password is blank

Comment: can u correct this code or guide me to access my server database and reterive table data 
with servername : 192.168.0.204  db name : reportdb2  & table name : Table1
user name: sa password is blank

Comment: here you mention  SSPI means that it is using windows authentication (the first option). If you enter a user name and a password then the VBA code needs to be changed. So what to change if I want to access username as sa with no password.

Comment: The IP address is already in the above code (as you can see). Also, the database is already in the above code. Now I also changed the username and password for you. I sure hope this resolves all obstacles and you can run the code without problems.

Comment: Yes first error removed.It connect to server but it is not populating records from the table. even I check with MsgBox rstResult.RecordCount it is showing -1 and for next statement error message is "subscript out range."

Comment: I am glad that the question of "connecting to the server" is resolved and fixed. For further questions, please open up a new question and close this one as solved. This Q&A is already way too big to add to it. But you can add a reference here to the new question and I will be sure to help you with that as well.